# How to not create many classes just for serialising nested JSON payload?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I've JSON message coming in from rabbitmq and has the following format:

```
{
   messageId: 123,
   content: {
      id: "P123456",
      status: false,
      error: {
         description: "Something has gone wrong",
         id: 'E400'
      }
   }
}
```

As you can see, the message has a few nested objects within them.

When this message comes in, I will serialise it using Jackson. Right now, however, I have to create multiple classes just for one single message.

In the example message above, I have to create 3 classes just for serialising and transforming it into a class `MainMessage`, like so:

```
public class MainMessage {
   private int messageId;
   private MessageContentObject content;

   // getters/setters...
}

public class MessageContentObject {
   private String id;
   private boolean status;
   private MessageErrorObject error;

   // getters/setters...
}


public class MessageErrorObject {
   private String description;
   private string id;

   // getters/setters...
}
```

This feels very cumbersome because in some of the messages, the nesting can be pretty deep and I will have to create a lot of classes just for the purpose of having the JSON payload transformed into the `MainMessage` class object. The `MessageContentObject` and `MessageErrorObject` are mostly redundant because I will never use the classes directly anywhere else in the code. I would still the values in them through `MainMessage` though, for example:

```
@RabbitListener
public void consumeMessage(MainMessage msg) {
   System.out.println(msg.getContent().getError().getDescription());
}
```

I'm using Spring with Spring Boot.
Is this really the only way I can do when it comes to dealing with nested JSON payloads?

Comment: u can store nested json into string in ````MainMessage```` object **because I will never use them anywhere else in the code**

Comment: @hosseinrasekhi If I store them as strings in `MainMessage`, how would I access the values in them later? I think I should also clarify that I would still use the values in them, just that I don't think I would use them independently. I've updated my question on this part with an example of what I will eventually need when accessing the `MainMessage`

Comment: if you are not using them, you can store it in `Map`

Comment: @Deadpool I'm pretty new to Spring. Is there an example on how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

First, when the message comes in you **Deserialize** it.

Now, if you don't want to create the whole data structure to look like your incoming JSON, you can go for a `Map` like this

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;

public class Message {

    private final Map<String, Object> details;

    @JsonCreator // Deserialize the JSON using this creator
    public Message(final Map<String, Object> details) {

      super();
      this.details = details;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter // Serialize this class using the data from the map
    public Map<String, Object> getDetails() {

      return Collections.unmodifiableMap(details);
    }
}
```

In this way, you won't need to change your `Message` class every time your incoming JSON changes.

However, this approach is useful only when you'll not be manipulating the data too much.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to create the whole data structure or you only need a small portion of the response recieved at a time you can use `Jackson JsonNode`

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
public class Message {
    private JsonNode messageDetails;

    /**
     * Constructor used to transform your object into jsonNode.
     *
     * @param messageDetailsResponse
     */
    public Message(Object messageDetailsResponse) {
      this.messageDetails = JsonUtils.getNode(messageDetailsResponse);
    }

    //Simply create getters for accessing the data you want when you want it
    public String getId() {
      return messageDetails.findValue("messageId").asText();
    }

    //You can also use it later to map a portion of response to an model class
        public Content getContent(){
        return JsonUtils.fromJsonNode(messageDetails.get("content"),Content.class)
        }
  }
```

The Code for JsonUtils

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

   @Slf4j
    final public class JsonUtils {
      /**
       * The Object Mapper constant to deal with JSON to/from conversion activities.
       */
      private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

      public static JsonNode getNode(Object anyObject) {

        try {
          return OBJECT_MAPPER.readTree(OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsBytes(anyObject));
        } catch (IOException e) {
          log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
      }

      public static <T> T fromJsonNode(final JsonNode node, final Class<T> clazz)
          throws JsonProcessingException {
        return OBJECT_MAPPER.treeToValue(node, clazz);
      }
```

Answer (score -2):

Some suggestions:

1. Consider using Lombok to reduce the code you need to write (getters setters etc.) - will make creating classes less of a problem.
2. Consider using static inner classes - will mean you need less files.
3. If you still prefer to not write your classes down, you can deserealise to a String and traverse it using Gson or similar libraries.

Comment: If possible, I'd like to receive an explanation for the down votes, so I can improve